# Transfer all messages of thunderbird with windows 7 to thunderbird ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: ubuntu, windows, backup, thunderbird

How can I transfer all messages and contacts of thunderbird with windows 7 to thunderbird ubuntu 14.04?

I know that have a free app called [mozbackup](http://mozbackup.jasnapaka.com/). But it don't works with linux.

There a way that can I make this moving?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the ImportExportTools Add-on for Thunderbird. The export your data as a file and import it on the new machine.